# qtranslate loading the wrong language

Tags: translation, plugin-qtranslate

I have the following problem.
I'm translating a website in 2 languages - Bulgarian and English.

Let say that I search a page in Bulgarian. The results that google disply are in Bulgarian language, but when I click on one of the links(google results) it loads the English version of the page, not Bulgarian.

I'm looking for a solution for this problem, but I can't find anything.

Comment: add this code in functions.php file `add_action('init',function(){ echo  get_locale();  exit; });` it should print bg_BG. otherwise, you can check by accessing your website like `website.com/?lang=bg` . try this

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the advice. I will try it and I will post an update.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that events callendar is inited before qtranslate, Tribe__Events__Main::instance() :

```
       // let's initialize tec silly-early to avoid fatals with upgrades from 3.x to 4.x
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'plugins_loaded' ), 0 );
```

simple hack was to create a plugin named 1fix with code:

```
 add_action( 'plugins_loaded', '__fix_tribe_init', 0 );

  function __fix_tribe_init(){
     global $locale;

     if(preg_match('/^\/ru\//',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
         $locale = 'ru_RU';
     } 
}
```

that completely solved my problem